# Unify products in the product category of woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, woocommerce

I have some products that have an ACF field called part_number. Many of the products have the same code, how can I make this function show me only 1 product with the same code? Ex: if I have 10 products and 5 have the same code it should show me 6 products.

```
  function remove_pages_from_search($query) {
     if ($query->is_product_category) {
        $query->set(


        );
     }
     return $query;
   }
   add_filter('pre_get_posts','remove_pages_from_search');
```

Comment: How you will decide which one needs to be displayed out of 5?

Comment: it is indifferent they are all the same

Comment: No I mean let's say you have 10 products and 1-5 products are unique but 6-10 has the same code so now how do you decide from 6-10 products which one to keep and display?